# Identify position range values within a vector

Tags: r

I was wondering if there would be the possibility to identify the position of the range values according to a condition. This condition is determined by the longest sequence of values lower than 3.

For instance,

```
x <- c(4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1)
```

Desired output:

```
c(7:15)
```

It may be that `split()` and `rle()` could be useful in this case but any help will be more than helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the `rle` on `x < 3`, then find `which` of the `TRUE`s is `max`. Then `sum` the lengths before the match plus one as well as the match itself (which will be the final position). Finally do a `seq`uence with the values.

```
rl <- rle(x < 3)
w <- which(rl$lengths == max(rl$lengths) & rl$values)
do.call(seq.int, list(sum(rl$lengths[1:(w - 1)]) + 1, sum(rl$lengths[1:w])))
# [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```